# Stacks dealing racognizng strings in a language, keep getting error, it's a array based implementation

Tags: java, stack

I am trying to implement an algorithm "recongnizng strings in a languages "

> L = {'w$w' : w is a possible empty string of characters other than $,
>   w' = reverse(w)}

I get an error saying  where `ch = aString[i];` : the type of expression must be an array type but resolved to string

also where `stackTop = aStack.pop();` but here however it's asking to cast to char

'
   import java.util.Stack;

public class Stacks 
    {

```
public static void main(String[] args){
boolean eval = isInLanguage("sod$dos");

System.out.println(eval);


}




static //   astack.createStack();
    boolean isInLanguage(String aString){
    Stack<Character> aStack = new Stack<>(); 


    int i = 0;
    char ch = aString.charAt(i);
    while (ch != '$') {
        aStack.push(ch);
        i++;
    }
    //Skip the $
    ++i;

    // match the reverse of w
    boolean inLanguage = true; // assume string is in language
    while (inLanguage && i < aString.length()) {
        char stackTop;
        ch = aString.charAt(i);;
        try {
            stackTop =  (char) aStack.pop();
            if (stackTop == ch) {
                i++;
            } else {
                // top of stack is not ch(Charecter do not match)
                inLanguage = false; // reject string

            }
        } catch (StackException e) {
            // aStack.poo() failed, astack is empty (first, half of Stirng
            // is short than second half)

            inLanguage = false;
        }
    }

    if (inLanguage && aStack.isEmpty()) {
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;

    }
}
```

}

'

I just made the necessary changes but now, it will compile but it doesnt seem to stop and doesn't output anything, i am expecting a true in the console

Answer (score 1):

1. In java, you use aString.chatAt(i), not as you did. A String is not an array of chars, as it is in C.
2. Why don't you use  java.util.Stack  ?

   import java.util.Stack;

and

```
Stack<Character> aStack = new Stack<>();
```

should do the work.

Comment: I just edited my code and entered in what you told me, but now the program hangs up and doesn't out put anything

Answer (score 0):

You cannot `[]` index into a String in Java. Try:

```
ch = aString.charAt(i);
```